# Require constant-defining files at once or by utilisation in PHP?

Tags: php, constants, require

I have about 20 files containing 10-15 times this:

```
define('someConstantName','stringBetween10and200Chars');
```

those are all critical for the app, but each constants-file is parallel to an app page.

For example, **index.php** will require **index_constants.php** so on so forth.

The question is, should I make one file of all constant-definitions together, or require different files relatively to the pages they belong to.

I'm asking in terms of speed and efficiency.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the **performance** (since a file with useless data will be included whereas the page needs only one) then put a single file for each page but if you looking for **ease/simplicity** then you can put them in a single file (if you think it will not create any sort of complexity for you). Thanks...

Comment: right, but if i require it once, it will only be slow once.

i guess that's something to think about too. just how slow it would be I'm not quite sure.

Comment: @Gal: If you use require_once this will even increase the slowness because php will have first check whether or not the file has been already included. Thanks